Update i18n translation files
I am using i18n-react in my app. Right now for dev purposes I request translated files through Weblate's API but when we deploy the project we use local json files in utils/i18n to show translation.
I was wondering if I could write these translations to json files while requesting them from Weblate? I tried tinkering around with saveMissing and saveMissingTo but it doesn't seem to do what I need.
import i18next from "i18next";
import I18NextHttpBackend from "i18next-http-backend";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import { getLanguageData } from "./languageData";

const languageData = getLanguageData();

i18next
  .use(I18NextHttpBackend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: "ru",
    lng: "en",
    keySeparator: ".",
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
    saveMissingTo: "all",
    ...languageData,
  });

export default i18next;

and here's where I decide what data to give depending on NODE_ENV:
import translationEN from "./en/en.json";
import translationRU from "./ru/ru.json";

const WEBLATE_URL = "   https://weblate.hdcem.ru/api/";

const envMode = process.env.NODE_ENV;

const devLanguageData = {
  backend: {
    loadPath: `${WEBLATE_URL}translations/digital/zakaz/{{lng}}/file/`,
    addPath: "src/utils/i18n/{{lng}}/{{lng}}.json",
    customHeaders: {
      Authorization: process.env.REACT_APP_WEBLATE_API_KEY,
    },
  },
};

const resources = {
  resources: {
    en: {
      translation: translationEN,
    },
    ru: {
      translation: translationRU,
    },
  },
};

export const getLanguageData = () => {
  if (envMode === "development") return devLanguageData;
  if (envMode === "production") return resources;

  return resources;
};

